# How to delete gtempaccount?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

I keep getting sign-in attempt emails from hackers trying to login and I cannot login to my gtemp account as I don't know how to. Any way to delete it entirely from G Suite admin?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A gtempaccount is a [conflicting account](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/1699308). This happens when you create a G Suite account using the same address as one which was previously used when signing up for another Google Service when the account was in use with a different email provider.

The password may or may not be the same as what you use on your G Suite account. To recover the account you will need to use the [forgotten password workflow](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/41078).

As a G Suite Administrator, you can [Find and manage existing Google Accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6178640).